# jQuery multiple events to trigger the same function (the second event include specific element)

Tags: jquery, events

I have to trigger a function on 2 events.
The first event is keyup (I know how to trigger this).
The second event is click on a specific button.

Currently I know hot to trigger the first event as I said
I use the following code:

```
emailPartner.on('keyup', function () {
    emailPartner.parent().removeClass('error-sign-up');
    $('.server').remove()
}
```

How do I trigger on both of the event?

Comment: Do you want to add your sample code?

Comment: @ Balázs Varga-I need a click on specific button I have

Answer (score 1):

Adding multiple event listeners to element is possible by adding events separated by space as first argument to `on`

```
$('#emailPartner, #myButton').on('keyup click', function () {
    emailPartner.parent().removeClass('error-sign-up');
    $('.server').remove();
});
```

Assuming that your `input` id is emailPartner and `button` id is myButton on which you want to trigger these events.

See jQuery Docs: http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: @Tushar- it doesn't get in to the function this way

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in this way, if you don't specify a function inside an event, it will trigger it:

```
emailPartner.on('keyup',function(){
    emailPartner.parent().removeClass('error-sign-up');
    $('.server').remove()
}).click(function(){
    $(this).keyup();
});
```

Or like mentioned in another answer, you can set multiple events for a function using on():

```
emailPartner.on('click,keyup',function(){ //...
```

Comment: it doesn't get in to the function this way (on click)

Comment: Both of the solutions was always worked for me... I don't know why you have prblems with that... :/

Comment: this should work, but it's difficult to read as the chaining is completely unnecessary and provides no real function.

Answer (score 0):

You have two elements, each with different events, right?

Take the event handler and place it in its own function, and attach it as the handler for both events.

```
var emailPartner = $('...'),
    myButton = $('...');

function myEventHandler() {
  emailPartner.parent().removeClass('error-sign-up');
  $('.server').remove()
}

emailPartner.on('keyup', myEventHandler);
myButton.on('click', myEventHandler);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following code :

```
emailPartner.on({
keyup:function () {...}, 
click:function() {....} 
}) ;
```

**Update :**

```
emailPartner.on('event1 event2 event3', function() {
...
}) ;
```

Comment: if this works, this is nice to group events on same element together. however, each event calls a different function. the OP wants the same function. granted they could call the same function, but it's an unnecesary duplicating of code reducing maintainability.